# intellij IDEA idea hided top bar

Tags: intellij-idea, panel

how can i return this top panel with debuger,git, run e.t.c ?
I tried to google it, but didn't find any solution
[image]

Answer (score 0):

View | Appearance | **Navigation Bar**.